# Release memory in ARC based APP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, viewdidunload

I am using a lot of `NSDictionaries` and `NSArrays` ,so currently am allocating everything at `viewDidload` and making everything nil in `ViewDidDisappear`.

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  loginDictionary=nil;
}
```

Now my memory will get down right?

Comment: Yes, excluding other oversights such as strong reference cycles

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have any other references to the object pointed to by `loginDictionary`, the memory should go down a bit. You can use Instruments to check that.